# How do I distribute my default settings plist file with a single known name, and have a different file depending on the selected target?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, target

I want my iOS app to read default settings from a configuration file. It will be a plist file. The source code should have the path and name of the file hard-coded and my code wold just open the file and read the contents at startup. But I would need to have two files with the same name and path in the Xcode project to do it this way. Of course, each file would be for a different target and only one would get included in the distribution package.

I have not investigated renaming files in a build script. I hope there is a better way.

I have considered having different file names and then searching for the file within the known relative path. This seems easy and is the option I will go with if there is no simpler or more clever way to do this.

So is there a way to pick from two different files, based on the selected target of the app, and have that file end up in the distribution package with a specific name (always the same name)?

Answer (score 0):

> There are different approaches that can achieve it. One is to create >different targets, each one of which employs different Info.plist. Each >time a target is selected, a different Info.plist will be used, hence we >will be able to differentiate variables like token, URLs for different >builds. The alternative approach is to put your build configuration >settings into .xcconfig files and refer those in your project info.
>   It could also be achieved by using Bundle Identifiers

I hope this link will be helpful to you,
https://www.appcoda.com/xcconfig-guide/
https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets

Comment: I have two targets. I have two plist files with the standard app settings needed by the OS. I want to have some other file contain my default user settings so that I can iterate through them all and read them into a dictionary in the app. But with some other file, I can't use a single path and file name to open the file because I can't have two files of the same name in the same place in the source code tree. I could place the name or path of this file in the standard plist file since I think the app knows that files name and location without me doing anything special.